# Android - how to check object is existed in layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to know how to chech whether object is existed in layout.

To make clear, I want to check ListView is existed in layout for different screen resolution. If client device is tablet, I'll process for ListView and will make some action. If client device is mobile, I'll ignore this ListView and set visible mode to GONE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To know whether object exists or not, just try to find it with findViewById and compare result to null

Comment: Great. That's what I want to know.

Answer (score 2):

You should define the default (say, phone) layout in /res/layout and the tablet layout in /res/layout-w720dp or something similar. See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts) for more information on qualifiers for layouts. Then you have defined your different layouting in xml and don't need to jump through hoops in code to make it fit to different screen types.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: This is a link to post on my blog (there is no advertising). I think it might help you think about the way you construct your app to deal with phones vs tablets.

http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/10/16/architecting-a-single-apk-app-to-handle-phones-and-tablets-on-android/

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your intention is to hide a listView from the  screen if the users device is not a tablet. This is easily done using different layouts for different as mentioned in Damians blog post.

However the new correct way of doing this is to use fragments. The basic idea is you combine the code and layout into a fragment and only use the fragment if there is space on the screen. This means that your screen would be formed of 1 fragment if phone and two if tablet, one of which would contain and code for your listView.

[Fragments - Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html)